# Did Palpatine have a plan if Padme survived?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader, padme

I quite like the theory that Padme didn't die of childbirth - Palpatine stole her life force to save Darth Vader.  In canon, though, Padme died entirely unrelated to Palpatine and Vader.  But when Vader was revived and given his armor, his first action was to ask about Padme.  Palpatine's reveal that she is dead and Vader killed her is largely what pushes Vader permanently to the Dark Side.

But, whether in canon or the popular theory, Palpatine didn't intend to kill Padme when he was manipulating Anakin.  In canon, she simply died of sadness.  In the theory, she died because Vader was so badly burned that he almost died, but Palpatine didn't expect that outcome.

So what was Palpatine's plan if Padme had lived?  The largest playing card Palpatine had in turning Anakin into Vader was that Padme would die if he didn't turn.  If she was alive when he became Vader, he wouldn't have been as devoted to Palpatine.

So did Palpatine have a plan for Padme surviving?  Or was he just assuming the events of Order 66 and its aftermath would kill her?

Comment: I'm guessing the answer is "he foresaw her death" and that's really all the planning he needed to do.

Comment: Palpatine: "Padme? Oh she hates you. She's with Obi-wan now. Look, she's even updated her Facebook status. She even called you a L-O-S-E-R. No, you cannot check on your phone, we forbid everyone but the highest Sith to have Facebook. Now go turn to the dark side and kill people."

Comment: Methinks Palpatine always backdates his predictions to maintain he predicted it.

Comment: Everyone has a plan until Padme punches them in the face.

Comment: Assume makes an ass of you and (Pad)me.